# Difference between 2.4Ghz ISM and IEEE 802.11 frequency bands?

Tags: wireless, network, nrf24l01

It may be a silly question to ask the difference between a **frequency band** and a **standard protocol** which is represented by **IEEE**.
But, I've been reading the wikipedia page of the **IEEE 802.11** and it says that the frequncy band is **2.4Ghz ISM** and i was massively confused on this problem.

> What's the difference between 802.11 and 2.4Ghz and why they can't be used to be connected together(like connecting an **nRF24L01** to a **Wireless LAN**?

The wikipedia page of 802.11 says that it uses the 2.4Ghz ISM band. So there should be no problem connecting an nRF to a Wireless LAN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between the 300-3300 Hz telephone bandwidth and spoken French?  Why can't an English speaker and a Japanese speaker understand each other, when they can both communicate with their countrymen using the same type of telephone?

Comment: @Chris I understand this much... I was just wondering would it be possible to create a library for nRF24l01 and let him speak 802.11 or not :)

Comment: If we hand you a dictionary, can you speak Japanese?  Same issue here.  Though interestingly, with pre-computation, you can get an nRF24L01 to utter a short intelligible phrase in BTLE.  However, it cannot receive or carry on a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For radios to communicate, the channels must match, the channel spacings must match, the type of modulation must be compatible (software radio compatible), the packet timing and pre-ambles must match. As well as ErrorCorrection.

Comment: Not too much, but really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you first learn a bit more about [wireless communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless)

Your question is like asking the difference between a concrete road and yellow cars. Both are needed to transport things and are not related but you cannot compare them directly.

A frequency band and a IEEE standard are related but different things. That [ISM band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band) tells which frequencies can be used.

IEEE 802.11 is a standard describing how the communications take place. It might dictate what frequency band is used but does not have to. Note how IEEE 802.11 is divided into many substandards like IEEE 802.11n which can be used at both 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz. IEEE 802.11a uses only 5 GHz.

Bluetooth also uses the same 2.4 GHz ISM band, that does not mean Bluetooth devices can communicate with WiFi devices (IEEE 802.11).

The nRF24L01 is just a transceiver, it does not "speak" WiFi (IEEE 802.11) so like Bluetooth, it cannot "talk" WiFi. Note how that chip has 126 RF channels in the 2.4 GHz band. Now compare that to what WiFi uses or Bluetooth.

The  fact that this chip does use the 2.4 GHz ISM band means nothing. **Many** devices and standards use this band because it can be used "freely" around the world. But in order for two devices to be able to communicate they need to speak the same language, in the communication world that is called a protocol. IEEE 802.11 is a protocol so is Bluetooth, HomeRF, ZigBee etc. They're all different protocols using the same frequency band.

Comment: Great description. :)